# Win32 and catching WM_SIZE message outside WindowProcedure

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a function which processes messages and there I catch certain messages outside WindowProcedure to trigger wanted behavior.

The problem is that while it seems like other messages are working as needed, I can't catch the `WM_SIZE` message for some reason.
`WM_SIZE` is seen in the WindowProcedure, but I can't find a reason why it is not seen by my function.
Is the problem on my method of reading the current `HWND`?

The function currently is:

```
// OS MESSAGES
int OSMessages(void)
{
  MSG msg;
  HWND actwnd = GetActiveWindow();

  if ( PeekMessage(&msg, actwnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) )
  {

    if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
    {
      printf("QUIT");
      return -1;
    }
    else if (msg.message == WM_SIZE)
    {
      printf("RESIZE");
      return 1;
    }

    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not related to your particular problem, but your loop has another hidden problem you should be aware of: [The dangers of filtering window messages](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050209-00/?p=36493).

Comment: Yes I noticed that also when rechecking it. I got rid of the filtering. But thank you for pointing it out! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A message loop can only ever see messages that are **posted** to the calling thread's message queue.  `WM_SIZE`, however, is not a posted message, it is a **sent** message.  A sent message is delivered *directly* to a window's message procedure without going through the message queue at all (although a message loop has some influence on *when* a sent message is delivered to the message procedure).

That is why your message loop is not seeing `WM_SIZE`.  If you need it, you will have to subclass the target window itself using [`SetWindowsLong/Ptr()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx) or [`SetWindowsSubclass()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102.aspx) to hook in your own window procedure.

See MSDN for more details:

[Messages and Message Queues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632590.aspx)

[Subclassing Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx)

Comment: If the window is defined by the program, then there would be no need for subclassing or hooking, the code can just be placed in the window procedure.

Answer (score 3):

`WM_SIZE` is sent directly to the window procedure. It does not travel via the message queue. This is quite normal and there are a large class of messages that are delivered in this, synchronously rather than via the asynchronous message queue.

To intercept this message you should place your code in the window's window procedure.

Comment: Is there any way to send data from Window's window procedure back to the mainloop?
I mean I now have a main project file/main gameloop and OS related functions are seperated to its own source file, I haven't found a way to let the main game loop know that the WM_SIZE event is being triggered.

Comment: @Mikko-PenttiEinariEronen: What's so special about handling events inside your message loop implementation that you couldn't handle elsewhere, say, in a dedicated function? Why do you assume, that you absolutely must handle certain messages in your message loop. Sounds like a design issue rather than a programming problem. And to answer your immediate question: No, you cannot go back in time.

Comment: I don't mind where the messages are handled in, the problem is that my main.cpp is meant to be OS independent, so I have OSMessages() for each operating system currently in question. If it's Windows, I handle window messages there. However the problem simply is that I haven't found a way to pass WM_SIZE information back to the game engine from OSMessages(). I have tried custom message and PostMessage() under Window Procedure WM_SIZE, but that only gets triggered once when the window is created.

Comment: [SOLUTION] I "fixed" this by defining a global variable ENGINE_WINDOW_RESIZED which I can set and check across the game engine.

Comment: @Mikko-PenttiEinariEronen are your game windows wrapped in portable classes? Your main code could define a callback function that gets passed to your window class so it could call back to the main code when needed.

Comment: I avoided wrapping a window to a class since with Win32 API it's a bit of a fiddle. It is a good idea though. Thank you for that. Perhaps I'll wrap it in a class at some point.